# Xcode 8.2.1 with macOS Sierra Server

Tags: macos, xcode, server.app

I updated to Sierra and my Xcode server has stopped working. I'm trying to set Xcode 8.2.1 (8C1002) as the build version and all I get is

> This version of Xcode is not supported

I'm working on Swift 2.3 and can't yet update to Xcode 8.3.

At the moment it looks like my option is to downgrade to El Capitan.

Is there any other way to get Xcode 8.2.1 working on Sierra Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its looks like the El Capitan -> Sierra upgrade process was the culprit.

Deleting the server.app and reinstalling from the App Store seems to have worked.

Comment: This is no logical solution considering the question (it may be valid though).